# How do I use Django piston to return a response in text/plain?

Tags: python, django, rest, http, django-piston

I want to NOT serialize anything. I just want to return what is equivalent to `HttpResponse(blah)`

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a string emitter, and not one of the built-in JSONEmitter, XMLEmitter, etc.

Have a look at the docs for emitters: https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation

And the existing emitter definitions here: 
https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/c4b2d21db51a/piston/emitters.py

A definition of a plain text emitter might look like this:

```
from piston.emitters import Emitter
from piston.utils import Mimer    

class TextEmitter(Emitter):
    def render(self, request):
        return self.construct()
Emitter.register('text', TextEmitter)
Mimer.register('text', None, ('text/plain',))
```

You'd get your resource to use this emitter in your urls.py like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^blogposts$', resource_here, { 'emitter_format': 'text' }),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I found, from [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects):

```
HttpResponse("Text only, please.", content_type="text/plain")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to user85461's answer, when you make a text emitter, you'll want to also make a text Mimer.  I wrote the following code with works with Piston 0.2.2

```python
from piston.emitters import Emitter
from piston.utils import Mimer

class TextEmitter(Emitter):
    def render(self, request):
        return self.construct()
Emitter.register('text', TextEmitter, ('text/plain',))
Mimer.register(lambda x: QueryDict(x), ('text/plain',))
```

Add this snippet somewhere that will get run before your handlers.  I put it in my API `urls.py` above where I created my `Resources` with

```
resource_handler = Resource(handler=SomeHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your view:

```
class HttpResponsePlain(django.http.HttpResponse):

    def serialize(self):            return self.content
    def serialize_headers(self):    return ''

return HttpResponsePlain(content = 'That is plain text response!')
```